# Using Google patent api

Tags: python, google-api

I simply want to find out the owner of a patent using Python and the Google patent search API.

```
import urllib2
import json

url = ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/patent?' +
       'v=1.0&q=barack%20obama')

request = urllib2.Request(url, None, {})
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

# Process the JSON string.
print json.load(response)
# now have some fun with the results...
```

This result does not tell about assignee. How can I get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Google patents API is deprecated ("[The Google Patent Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011.](https://developers.google.com/patent-search/)").  I don't think the data you get is reliable.

I'm not sure whether the Google terms of service allows going against individual Google patent pages, but one strategy might be to use search to get a list of results, then use something like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse each result.

Example:

```
import urllib2
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/patent?' +
       'v=1.0&q=barack%20obama')
request = urllib2.Request(url, None, {})
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
jsonResponse = json.load(response)
responseData=jsonResponse['responseData']
results = responseData["results"]

print "This doesn't work, no assignee data..."
for result in results:
    print "patent no.: ", result["patentNumber"]
    print "assignee: ", result["assignee"]
    print " "

print "...but this seems to."
for result in results:
    URL = "https://www.google.com/patents/"+result["patentNumber"]
    req = urllib2.Request(URL, headers={'User-Agent' : "python"})
    _file = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    patent_html = _file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(patent_html, 'html.parser')
    patentNumber = soup.find("span", { "class" : "patent-number" }).text
    assigneeMetaTag = soup.find("meta", { "scheme" : "assignee"})
    patentAssignee = assigneeMetaTag.attrs["content"]
    print "patent no.: ", patentNumber
    print "assignee: ", patentAssignee
    print " "
```

For me this prints out:

```
This doesn't work, no assignee data...
patent no.:  US20110022394
assignee:

patent no.:  US20140089323
assignee:

patent no.:  US8117227
assignee:

patent no.:  CA2702937C
assignee:

...but this seems to.
patent no.:  US 20110022394 A1
assignee:  Thomas Wide

patent no.:  US 20140089323 A1
assignee:  Appinions Inc.

patent no.:  US 8117227 B2
assignee:  Scuola Normale Superiore Di Pisa

patent no.:  CA 2702937 C
assignee:  Neil S. Roseman
```

One note of caution, I believe you're only going to get the assignee as of the date the patent was issued; not the current assignee, in cases where it has been transferred.

Comment: Also, if there's an issue with Google's terms of service, you can try going against the USPTO's own API.  A Wikipedia editor named Josh Cogliati has made a number of Python routines available under the GPL to parse those pages:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Jrincayc/Patent_utils

Answer (score 4):

### Use https://www.patentsview.org/ instead...

A while back, I was also using the Google patent search API.  It's gone.  And so is the previously mentioned ipstreet API.

But I did discover https://www.patentsview.org/, which appears to have the blessing of the USPTO and a comprehensive API.  For starters, take a look at:

```
https://www.patentsview.org/api/query-language.html
```

For now, I'm updating my parser to use this instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `patent_client`! It's a python module that searches the live USPTO and EPO databases using a Django-style API. The results from any query can then be cast into pandas DataFrames or Series with a simple `.to_pandas()` call.

For patent ownership, there's two ways to go about it. You can check the "assignee" field of a Patent, or search the assignment records:

```py
from patent_client import Assignment, Patent

# Method 1 - Look at the Assignee listed on the face of a patent

pat = Patent.objects.get("patent number")
pat.assignees
# Gives a list of assignees listed on the patent

# Method 2 - Search Assignment records for recorded assignments
assignments = Assignment.objects.filter(patent_number="patent_number")
# Gives a list of assignment records that include the patent,
# You can browse through the authoritative chain of title as 
# recorded with the USPTO
```

A great place to start is the [User Guide Introduction](https://pypi.org/project/patent-client/)

[image: Patent Client Logo]

[PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/patent-client/) | [GitHub](https://github.com/parkerhancock/patent_client) | [Docs](https://patent-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

(Full disclosure - I'm the author and maintainer of patent_client)

Answer (score -2):

As codinggatty said, the Google Patents API has been depricated and scraping it can be spotty. If you are looking for patent data via an RESTful API endpoint, [IP Street](http://www.ipstreet.com/) is the right way to go.  It's pretty straight forward and you can be up and running in no time.

To find the owner of a patent, you `POST` a patent number in your query to `https://api.ipstreet.com/v1/data/patent`.

Here is an example in python 3.X:

```
import requests
import json

def search_by_patent_number(input):
    """Takes one or more patent numbers and returns a patent data json object"""
    endpoint = 'https://api.ipstreet.com/v1/data/patent'
    headers = {'x-api-key': "YOUR-API-KEY"}
    payload = json.dumps({'q': {'patent_number': input}})

    r = requests.post(url=endpoint, headers=headers, data=payload)

    print(r.text)
    return r.json()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    response = search_by_patent_number(['8541236','7653452'])

    for asset in response['Assets']:
        print(asset['application_date'])
```

You can find more code examples at the IP Street Github repo here: https://github.com/IPStreet/HelloWorld

Here is their developer docs page: http://www.ipstreet.com/

Comment: amazing ...Thanks for the helps . Really helpful

Comment: @Reed, you appear to be affiliated with IP Street ("Head of Product", per LinkedIn). You should disclose that when you post answers positing your commercial product or service as a solution.

Comment: ipstreet.com appears to be defunct.