# Error : in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: javascript, google-patent-search

I got the following `error` when I implement **`patent search google`** in **`iframe`**.

```
in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

```js
document.getElementById("go_search").onclick = function() {
  myFunction();
};

function myFunction() {
  var patent_content = document.getElementById("patent_content").value;

  var html_content = '<iframe crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://patents.google.com/?q=' + patent_content + '&embedded=true" height="200" width="300"></iframe>';
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html_content;
}
```

```html
<h2>Google Patent Search</h2>
<form>
  <p>Paste your content</p>
  <textarea id="patent_content"></textarea>
  <input type="button" id="go_search" value="go" />
</form>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Please help me to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

**Error:**
In Chrome

```
patent.html:1 Refused to display 'https://patents.google.com/?q=fghfhfghfg' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
patent.html:24 GET https://patents.google.com/?q=fghfhfghfg net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
```

**Error:**
In Mozilla

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://patents.google.com/?q=dsfsdfsd&embedded=true does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: @ved I have tried something different. Kindly check my code...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The website https://patents.google.com has a [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) that allows only websites with the same domain (i.e., other Google websites only) to render its page in an `<iframe>`.

So you cannot embed their website into yours. Browsers when see that the response header contains `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`, they check your domain and block the rendering of the `<iframe>`. It is a security measure to avoid [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking).

Comment: There is any possible to implement to our own project?

Comment: This restriction is for browsers only. You can create a backend service that access that website (or API if available) and provides the results via an endpoint. So your website could send a request to your service (that would allow your domain to send requests, with CORS configuration, etc) and, via that service, you would retrieve data from Google patents

Comment: The answers of this question might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637023/using-google-patent-api

Comment: Thanks :-).. But they stopped the patent api services(https://developers.google.com/patent-search/v1/devguide).. :-)

Comment: Yes. Just checked that it has been deprecated, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, but all you have to do is grab the last bit of a youtube link.
For example, in this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUh2O8HylUM.

KUh2O8HylUM  - copy this and in the src="https://youtube.com/embed/*here*" as shown below.

```
<iframe src="https://youtube.com/embed/KUh2O8HylUM"
        width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: This does answer the question. It works for me as well :)

Comment: I embed this link(https://patents.google.com/?q=coin) not the youtube URL, which showing the error. Because this link not allowing the iframe... :-(